# on the chrome94,selenium can't location Elements

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

My testcase(write by selenium) used normally before chrome94. now my chromedriver version is 94,but my testCase  exception! cant location elements!
how can i deal with the question.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By; 
import org.testng.annotations.Test; 
public class LoginPdxbw { 
WebDriver driver; 
public void setUp() { 
     driver=login(userName,password); } 
     public void test_main() { 
     driver.findElement(By.className("person-name")).getText(); 
  } 
   @Test 
   public void run() { 
      setUp(); 
      test_main(); } 
   }
```

Comment: Your question is not making any sense. Please add relevant details about what failure you're getting, the HTML.

Comment: What is the exception/error?

Comment: driver.findElement(By.className("person-name")).getText();   this line error.execption:org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".person\-name"}..excute this statement i wait for 5s by thread.sleep。and i confirm this page loaded completed